# I'm trying to do a search and replace in MySQL using Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, search, wildcard

I am in the process of migrating content from another CMS to Wordpress. My challenge is to fix all the internal broken URLs contained in the field in question is 'post_content'.

In a nutshell i need to search integers in the broken URLs that were from the old CMS, and replace them with new values mapping to the correct Wordpress content IDs.

I have the old and new values mapped as integers in a table 'wp_postmeta' where 'post_id" are the new values and 'meta_value' are the old values:

```
post_id | meta_key   | meta_value
13533   | content_id | 30
13534   | content_id | 3094 
13535   | content_id | 4066
```

This is the SQL Query i have written so far, and I feel it's really close - but i need to do a search for 'meta_value' using a wildcard otherwise it won't work. I'm not sure how to do it, and hoping for some tips.

```
UPDATE wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, wp_postmeta.meta_value , wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE meta_key='content_id'
```

Thanks in advance - i'm new to SQL and it's taken me a day to get this far! :-)

Comment: Hi there - 'content_id' is the meta_key value, it's a key/value pair that's stored like that in the table. I need to use a wildcard statement with 'meta_value' because the integers such as the number 30 are inside of an HTML href markup. I know how to apply wildcards to strings or numbers, but not to a dynamic field (right term?)

Comment: I learned that a wildcard cannot be used with the SQL command REPLACE which makes sense. Is there a way around this or an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you have a sample data of your `meta_key` ? I hope this helps

I assume your `meta_keys` starts with something like this `3094`

```
UPDATE wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, wp_postmeta.meta_value , wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE meta_key LIKE '30%'
```

For more info refer to this link [WILDCARDS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)